# My assertEquals is returning the package name when I run a Maven Test

Tags: import, enums, constructor, tdd, assert

I have a TestEntry Class:

```java
@Test
void testFloatConstructor() {
    Entry floatTest = new Entry(1);
    assertEquals(floatTest.number, 1, "Test that the constructor sets 
       the Entry float to 1");
}
    
@Test
void testSymbolConstructor() {
    Symbol symbolTestSign = new Symbol(Symbol.MINUS);
    Entry symbolTest = new Entry(symbolTestSign);
    assertEquals(symbolTest.other, Symbol.MINUS, "Test that the 
        constructor sets the Symbol to - sign");
    }
```

and the actual Entry Class:

```java
float number;
Symbol other;
String str;
Type type;
    
public Entry(float value) {
    this.number = value; 
}
    
public Entry(Symbol which) {
    this.other = which;
}
```

The Test for `testFloatConstructor()` works fine but when I run `testSymbolConstructor()`, the *expected* just returns my package name (The *actual* is correct, returning -). What is causing this? Am I not constructing the symbol class correctly:

```java
enum Symbols {
    LEFT_BRACKET,
    RIGHT_BRACKET,
    TIMES,
    DIVIDE,
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    INVALID
}

public static final String MINUS = "-";
public static final String PLUS = "+";
String symbol;
    
public Symbol() {
    
}
    
public Symbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}
```

I haven't finished the Symbol Class yet as I'm programming with TDD and trying to get this Test to pass first. Even with hard-coding/cheating I can't get it to work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```java
assertEquals(symbolTest.other, Symbol.MINUS, "Test that the 
        constructor sets the Symbol to - sign");
```

you are comparing `symbolTest.other`, which is of type `Symbol` to `Symbol.MINUS`, which is type `String`. You probably want to write:

```java
assertEquals(symbolTest.other.symbol, Symbol.MINUS, "Test that the 
        constructor sets the Symbol to - sign");
```

And FYI, first argument to `assertEquals` is **expected** value, and second is **actual** value - that's why error message might be confusing for you.